"Elementary" Proof of Strong Law of Large Numbers
I came across a paper that a seemingly "elementary" proof of the strong law of large numbers, although I am having a lot of trouble understanding it since the author leaves a lot of justification to the reader or unexplained. (For those interested, it is called "An Elementary Proof of the Strong Law of Large Numbers by N. Etemadi)
We want to show that given $\mathbb{E}[X_1]<\infty$ and the $X_i$'s are i.i.d, that $S_n/n\to\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ almost surely. Here $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.
We assume WLOG that each $X_i\geq 0$, since we can split any $X$ into its positive and negative parts $X^+ = \max(0, X)$ and $X^-=-\min(0, X)$ and write $X=X^+-X^-$.
Now next we consider these "indicator" variables $$Y_n = X_n\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{X_i\leq i\}}=\begin{cases}
X_n, & X_i\leq i \\
0, & \text{o.w.}
\end{cases}$$
We now define $S_n^*=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, and now consider the subsequence $\{S_{n_k}\}$, where $n_k=\alpha^k$ for some $\alpha>1$.
Here is where I get very lost. I understand the goal is to use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma to show the claim is true for the subsequence.

We use Chebyshev's Inequality for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ to see that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_{n_k}^*-\mathbb{E}[S_{n_k}^*]}{n_k}\right|>\varepsilon\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Var}(S_{n_k}^*)}{n_k^2\varepsilon^2}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)\tag1$$
due to the independence of the $Y_i$'s.

At this point the proof starts to not make any sense, since I don't know how he formed the inequality

$$(1)\leq c\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]}{i^2}.$$

I understand how $\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)=\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]-(\mathbb{E}[Y_i])^2\leq\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2]$, but I don't know how he was able to get the $i^2$.
I was able to understand the next couple of steps. However, another thing I was unable to understand was the "monotonicity" step, since that was literally covered in one line:

Now from monotonicity of $S_n$ we can conclude that
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbb{E}[X_1]\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}\leq \alpha\mathbb{E}[X_1].$$

Where does he use $\alpha$ and how does he get this values?
Thank you so much for the help.

You should change $\mathbb{E}[X_1]<\infty$ to $\mathbb{E}|X_1|<\infty$.

Does it matter if it is $X_1$ or $|X_1|$?

This should be more or less the same argument as here https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/ which might be more digestible.
